# for loop to return exact match but need to update to return similar match

Tags: string, vba

i have existing code that works perfectly when taking user input in cell C3, searches the data table below it and displays all matching results for product codes neatly in the top few rows. I need to update this code to have some logic in the event it cannot find an exact match, but may have found a similar match. here is the existing code:

```
    Option Compare Text
    Sub MultipleLkp()

    Dim numRows As Integer, numCols As Integer, i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer, PrimKey, lastColumn As Long
    Dim Trimkey As String


    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Worksheets("DashboardMain").Range("D3:R8").ClearContents
    Worksheets("DashboardMain").Range("C200").CurrentRegion.Select
    PrimKey = Worksheets("DashboardMain").Range("C3").Value
    numRows = Selection.Rows.Count
    numCols = Selection.Columns.Count
    j = 2
    lastColumn = Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=Range("A1"), Lookat:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False).Column

    'TrimKey is the variable replacing PrimKey but without spaces or hyphens.
    'allows user to input a model with or without " " or "-" in cell C3
    'can be modified to include more invalid characters
    Trimkey = Replace(Replace(PrimKey, " ", ""), "-", "")
    If Trimkey = "" Then
    Exit Sub
    End If
    'runs the loop and returns all matches; displays matches in rows 3 down until all matches found
    'does not have any logic if no match is found. need to add the "like" function?
    For i = 2 To numRows
        If Worksheets("DashboardMain").Cells(199 + i, 3).Value = Trimkey Then
            j = j + 1
            For k = 1 To lastColumn
                Worksheets("DashboardMain").Cells(j, 3 + k).Value = Worksheets("DashboardMain").Cells(199 + i, 3 + k).Value
            Next k
        End If
    Next I
end sub
```

ideally, if no exact match is found, a message box would display that would show possible matches and then the user could select potential match, which would then display according in the same area as if it were an exact match. any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

well, in my special Excel addin I have some special functions.

```
Public Function LEVEN(s1 As String, s2 As String) As Integer
    If Len(s1) > Len(s2) Then
        LEVEN = Levenshtein(s1, s2)
    Else
        LEVEN = Levenshtein(s2, s1)
    End If

End Function

Private Function Levenshtein(s1 As String, s2 As String) As Integer

Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim l1 As Integer
Dim l2 As Integer
Dim d() As Integer
Dim min1 As Integer
Dim min2 As Integer

l1 = Len(s1)
l2 = Len(s2)
ReDim d(l1, l2)
For i = 0 To l1
    d(i, 0) = i
Next
For j = 0 To l2
    d(0, j) = j
Next
For i = 1 To l1
    For j = 1 To l2
        If Mid(s1, i, 1) = Mid(s2, j, 1) Then
            d(i, j) = d(i - 1, j - 1)
        Else
            min1 = d(i - 1, j) + 1
            min2 = d(i, j - 1) + 1
            If min2 < min1 Then
                min1 = min2
            End If
            min2 = d(i - 1, j - 1) + 1
            If min2 < min1 Then
                min1 = min2
            End If
            d(i, j) = min1
        End If
    Next
Next
Levenshtein = d(l1, l2)
End Function
```

The LEVEN is based on Levenshtein's algorythm that measure one many changes (deletions, replacement) must be done to convert one text to another. This function measures distance between two strings. So, you could add boolean variable like boolExact that would have turn TRUE if

```
 If Worksheets("DashboardMain").Cells(199 + i, 3).Value = Trimkey Then
```

is fulfilled. And then, set conditional instruction checking if not boolExact, if so, run subroutine that would check

```
if LEVEN( Worksheets("DashboardMain").Cells(199 + i, 3).Value, TrimKey)>3
```

this is straightforward solution. Note, that two letter words are maximally two steps from each other, so LEVEN will return 2. You could possibly find useful compare LEVEN(x,y)/max(LEN(x), LEN(y)) to measure relative distance.

Comment: i will give this a shot. so I would paste this code into its own module, and my existing could would call the public function LEVEN? is that how this works?

Comment: exactly. This is not ready to use solution, but you should be able modify your code with this.

Comment: if I understand this correctly, the LEVEN function returns the number of character edits to make the 2 strings match. the 2 strings being the user input and the potential similar match on the data table. I could then set parameters to still return results if LEVEN is say < 3. which means the strings are similar but you'll need to edit 3 characters to get the exact...also, thank you for your input. this is very helpful